# Creating a simple DLL on Windows that writes on a file with GCC

Tags: windows, gcc, dll

I create a function called "run" in a library that write a simple text in a file. I inspired myself from this nice website:
http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppGppCallDll.htm

I have the following code:

lib_entry_point.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef UnitFunctionsH
#define UnitFunctionsH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    __declspec (dllexport) int run();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

lib_entry_point.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

#include "lib_entry_point.h"


int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
  return 1;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(      
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{  
  return 0;
}



int run()
{
        std::ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("example.txt");
        myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
        myfile.close();

        int ret;
        ret = 8765;
        
    return ret;
}
```

I compile this code with:

```
c:/gcc-13.2.0-no-debug/bin/g++ -c lib_entry_point.cpp
c:/gcc-13.2.0-no-debug/bin/g++ -o mylib.dll lib_entry_point.o
```

Then, I have a small C++ code to access it:

main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>

struct DllHandle
{
  DllHandle(const char * const filename)
    : h(LoadLibrary(filename)) {}
  ~DllHandle() { if (h) FreeLibrary(h); }
  const HINSTANCE Get() const { return h; }

  private:
  HINSTANCE h;
};

int main()
{
  //Obtain a handle to the DLL
  const DllHandle h("mylib.dll");
  if (!h.Get())
  {
    MessageBox(0,"Could not load DLL","UnitCallDll",MB_OK);
    return 1;
  }

  typedef const int (*runFunction)();
  const runFunction Answer
    = reinterpret_cast<runFunction>(
      GetProcAddress(h.Get(),"run"));

  if (!Answer) //No handle obtained
  {
    MessageBox(0,"Loading failed","UnitCallDll",MB_OK);
    return 1;
  }

  if (Answer() != 8765)
  {
    MessageBox(0,"Function failed","UnitCallDll",MB_OK);
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox(0,"Function successful!","UnitCallDll",MB_OK);
  }
}
```

I compile this code with:

```
c:/gcc-13.2.0-no-debug/bin/g++ -o exec.exe main.cpp
```

If I comment the lines

```
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
```

it runs perfectly and outputs "Function successful!" If I uncomment these lines however, it just crashes. I imagine this is a question of wrong memory address or .. ?